# Progress Dialog not rotating in xamarin android os 7

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, progressdialog

I am using `ZXing` nuget for scan QR code in my Xamarin Android application. I have added loader after scanned. I am calling api based on scanned data. But api takes time. I had written code for display loader it's not displaying properly on android 8 or android 9. But it's not rotating in android 7. What's wrong with my code?

My code is :

```
serverProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            serverProgressDialog.SetProgressStyle(ProgressDialogStyle.Spinner);
            serverProgressDialog.SetMessage("Contacting server. Please wait...");
            serverProgressDialog.Indeterminate = true;
            serverProgressDialog.SetCancelable(false);
            serverProgressDialog.Create();
            serverProgressDialog.ShowEvent += ServerProgressDialog_ShowEvent;
```

For show :

```
internal void ShowServerProgressDialog()
    {
        serverProgressDialog.Show();
    }
```

On ScanButton Click code :

```
imageBtn.Click += async delegate
            {
                scanner.AutoFocus();
                        var result = await scanner.Scan(options);
                        scanner.Cancel();
                        if (result != null)
                        {
                            SetTextboxValue(result.Text);
                            new Handler().PostDelayed(new Runnable(() =>
                                ShowServerProgressDialog()), 10);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            HideServerProgressDialog();
                        }
            };
```

On event show I am displaying dialog. Some how it's not rotating on android device os version 7.

Comment: Have you tried run ShowServerProgressDialog on UI thread? I just test it on android 7 and android 9, it both works well. (But I did not use ZXing).

Comment: Yes I had tried, But not working

Comment: Can you provide a sample with this problem so that I can test it on my side?